# Why is it important to ensure that the shapefiles have a spatial reference system when created?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system

Why is it important to ensure that shapefiles have a spatial reference system when created?

Comment: Please demonstrate that you have researched questions when asking them. See the help on [How do I ask a good question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Answer (score 7):

It sets the coordinate system that should be used for any data or coordinate values that are added (via import or editing) to the shapefile. Setting the coordinate system also ties the shapefile's data to the ground and provides a way for the software (and its users) to use the shapefile with other data that is using different coordinate systems.

Defining the coordinate system or spatial reference on a dataset also means that you can hand it off to someone else, or use it in 6 months or a year and not have to try to figure out the coordinate system. See how often that type of question ("I can't get this data to line up/show up in the right place") is posted here and on other forums.